# Did Crusaders' siege Nablus and then massacre Muslims?

Tags: catholic-church, crusades

I remember that I have heard in some lecture about some form of a siege over [Nablus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nablus) that ended up in indiscriminate killings of Muslims in the city. I vaguely remember that the events were said to have taken place in the 11th or the 13th century (?)

I also remember seeing some image of a Fresca that allegedly commemorates the event, and I was told it was painted in some Catholic church in Italy (?)

But, I cannot find any references to any of those matters.

Was it really an event or maybe I simply mix all the things?

Comment: Could you have confused Nablus and [Jerusalem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Jerusalem_(1099))? It's extremely likely that there are or were frescoes in Italy depicting the conquest of Jerusalem during the First Crusade.

Comment: Very reluctant to close a question with an answer....

Answer (score 4):

After some more web crawling done, I found the [event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nablus#Battle_of_Nablus_(1242)) - the battle of Nablus in the 13th century (1242). The fresco depicting the battle is indeed in Italy, in the Templar church of San Bevignate, Perugia.